# Javascript Pig Latin

Tags: javascript, html, string

I am trying to write a program which modifies words depending on whether they start with a consonant or a vowel. The rules are this:

- if a word begins with a vowel, the letter remains in place and 'way' is appended to the end of the word:
  apple --> appleway
- if a word begins with one consonant, that letter is moved to the end and 'ay' is appended:
  pig latin --> igpay atinlay
- if a word begins with two consonants, both letters are moved to the end and 'ay' is appended:
  grade --> adegray

Now because I am so new to Javascript but have some experience with other languages it wasnt too hard to write some code I am fairly confident in but for some reason it is not working. I think the problem is the part where the HTML element is accessed.

Here is my code:

```js
function PigTranslation(str) {
  var firstPos = FirstVowelPos(str);
  if (firstPos > 0) {
    return str.slice(firstPos) + str.slice(0, firstPos) + 'ay';
  }
  return str + "way";
}

function FirstVowelPos(str) {
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if ("aeiou".indexOf(str[i]) !== -1) {
      return i;
    }
  }
}

console.log(PigTranslation('Apple'));
```

The main problem I am having with learning javascript is that I dont know how to test it. I have been using [replit.com](https://replit.com/) but it seems like the only way to see if my code is working is to embed it into HTML. I tried running it from the shell but that doesnt work.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, _specific_ question.

Comment: `"aeiou".indexOf(str[i])` doesn't match uppercase letters

Comment: *I tried running it from the shell but that doesnt work.* - install nodejs and run it. If you need html support, run it in a browser instead

Comment: If repl.it isn't getting the job done, try jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

one option for running your code would be to open up your browser's console by right clicking on anywhere on the page, select inspect then choose the console tab. Paste your code and hit enter to run it.

Use the up arrow to to modify your code before re-running it.
[image]